# How can i run as much as desired to Timer? [Vb.Net]

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have 2 textbox and 2 timer. I first run it in timer1

```
if not textbox1.text = textbox2.text then
timer2.start
else
msgbox "finished"
end if
```

But timer1 skip reading when textbox1 is equal to textbox2 and always makes an error.
Do I have a chance to run timer2 as much as textbox2 instead?
For example, if textbox2 is 3, then timer2 runs 3 times. I can get rid of the textbox1 = textbox2 control and run the code that is actually correct and does not work. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by run the timer 3 times (or textbox value times to be more specific). Does that mean the timer should only tick (the event should fire) that amount of times and then stop?

Comment: Timer2 will click the button , if textbox2 is 3 then timer2 will click the button for 3 times. if click ratio is 3 then timer3 close down the itself enabled.

Comment: Show the code where you create and setup the timers. In which method is the code you´ve posted located ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding the question, but  I understand that you want to run some timer multiple times, and then continue to run another timer after x amount of times. This can be accomplished using something like this (I haven't tested this code):

```
Private WithEvents Timer1, Timer2, Timer3 As New System.Timers.Timer() With {.AutoReset = False}
Private NbTimesRun As New Dictionary(Of System.Timers.Timer, Integer) From {
    {Timer1, 0},
    {Timer2, 0},
    {Timer3, 0}
}

Private Sub Timer1_Elapsed(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Elapsed
    Debug.Print("Timer1 elapsed")
    ' Do some stuff here
    NbTimesRun(Timer1) += 1
    If NbTimesRun(Timer1) == 3 Then
        Timer2.Start()
    Else
        Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Elapsed(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Elapsed
    Debug.Print("Timer2 elapsed")
    ' Do some stuff here
    NbTimesRun(Timer2) += 1
    If NbTimesRun(Timer2) == 3 Then
        Timer3.Start()
    Else
        Timer2.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```

Etc.

This is a pretty bad design pattern, though, and you should instead use a single timer, check the number of times it has run and call a method depending on that number of times, for example. Timers need to be disposed, so override `Dispose` and call `TimerX.Dispose()`.

Comment: So thank you mr Audiopolis. it helped me after some editing. :)